# MAC php version not updating

Tags: php, macos

I'm trying to update php on my local machine by running the below command:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
```

The result of the command are as follows:

```
chris$ curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6
Detected OS X Mavericks 10.9 All ok.
Get packager.tgz
Unpack packager.tgz
Please type in your password, as we want to install this into /usr/local
Password:
Start packager (may take some time)
downloading http://php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.6-10.8-frontenddev-latest.dat
downloading http://php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.6-10.8/frontenddev/5.6-10.8-frontenddev-5.6.19-20160310-141036.tar.bz2

Installing package 5.6-10.8-frontenddev into root /
Package 5.6-10.8-frontenddev is already installed at version 5.6.19-20160310-141036. You wanted to install version 5.6.19-20160310-141036.
```

Then when I check the  version is saying version 5.4:

```
php -v
```

> PHP 5.4.30 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2014 23:43:29) 
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: Why not installing MAMP instead? Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526085/how-do-i-upgrade-php-in-mac-os-x

Comment: Or use [homebrew](http://brew.sh)

Comment: maybe you have to restart. BTW if it is already installed probably you can access it through php56 cmd instead of php, only shortcut must be updated. also try a phpinfo() through browser to see if apache is linked to old or new version.

Answer (score 3):

I am having a similar issue. I found this page: http://php-osx.liip.ch

It says this:

**Frequently Asked Questions**

Why does php -v on the command line still show my old version?

php-osx doesn't overwrite the php binaries installed by Apple, but installs everything in /usr/local/php5. The new php binary is therefore in /usr/local/php5/bin/php.

You can also adjust your PATH do include that directory, eg. write into your ~/.profile file the following

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

It worked for my issue.

Comment: Hallelujah, you've saved me atleast a dozen more minutes of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

When you use, osx's Apache server, things start to get a  little complicated. I came across **MAMP** a few days ago. Try using it, it's really simple, flexible, and you don't need to hunt for each and every package separately. 
Here is a link [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info)